# React constructor called only once for same component rendered twice

Tags: reactjs

I expected this toggle to work but somehow the constructor of component `<A/>` is called only once. https://codesandbox.io/s/jvr720mz75

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = { toggle: false };
  render() {
    const { toggle } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {toggle ? <A prop={"A"} /> : <A prop={"B"} />}
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ toggle: !toggle })}>
          toggle
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("INIT");
    this.state = { content: props.prop };
  }

  render() {
    const { content } = this.state;
    return <div>{content}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I already found a workaround https://codesandbox.io/s/0qmnjow1jw.

```
<div style={{ display: toggle ? "none" : "block" }}>
  <A prop={"A"} />
</div>
<div style={{ display: toggle ? "block" : "none" }}>
  <A prop={"B"} />
</div>
```

I want to understand why the above code is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In react if you want to render same component multiple times and treat them as different then you need to provide them a unique `key`. Try the below code.

```
{toggle ? <A key="A" prop={"A"} /> : <A key="B" prop={"B"} />}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since that ternary statement renders results in an `<A>` component in either case, when the `<App>`'s state updates and changes `toggle`, React sees that there is still an `<A>` in the same place as before, but with a different `prop` prop. When React re-renders it does so by making as few changes as possible. So since this is the same class of element in the same place, React doesn't need to create a new element when `toggle` changes, only update the props of that `<A>` element.

Essentially, the line

```
{toggle ? <A prop="A"/> : <A prop="B"/> }
```

is equivalent to

```
<A prop={ toggle ? "A" : "B" }/>
```

which perhaps more clearly does not need to create a new `<A>` component, only update the existing one.

The problem then becomes that you set the `state.content` of the `<A>` using `props.prop` in the constructor, so the `state.content` is never updated. The cleanest way to fix this would be to use `props.prop` in the `render` method of the `<A>` component instead of `state.content`. So your `A` class would look like this:

```
class A extends Component {
    render() {
        const { prop } = this.props;
        return <div>{ prop }</div>;
    }
}
```

If you must take the `prop` prop and use it in the `<A>` component's state, you can use `componentDidUpdate`. Here's an example:

```
class A extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {content: props.prop};
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.prop !== this.props.prop) {
            this.setState({content: this.props.prop});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { content } = this.state;
        return <div>{ content }</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: My constructor is changing the structure of the props to provide a nice API, I just omitted this to give a minimal example (I know that this is not recommended ;-) ). But thanks for your explanation.

Comment: ah, then I'd recommend using the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. Updating an existing component is a lot cheaper than unmounting the old one and creating a new one.

Comment: Currently I do not have a perf problem and the code is much cleaner when I just add a key, as suggested by Raghav Garg's answer. But that's good to know if the perf becomes important!

Answer (score 1):

React will only call the constructor once. That's the expected outcome.
Looks like you're trying to update the state of the component A based on the props.
You could either use the prop directly or use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method, as Henry suggested. Another way is using the static method getDerivedStateFromProps to update the state based on the prop passed.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return ({
        content: props.prop
    });
}
```